# Whenever I run a simple prompt in Makersuite, it shows that "An internal Error has Occured", what to do?

Tags: google-api, google-generativeai, palm-api, makersuite

Whenever I run a simple prompt in Makersuite, it shows that "An internal Error has Occured", what to do?

I asked basic prompts like categorize and I was expecting a simple answer. But it just shows an internal error has occured.

Comment: It is difficult to debug the problem based on just what you've said. Getting details about the prompt and model you're using and other model parameters might be able to help. If you can update the question with as much information as you can, possibly including a screen shot illustrating what's going on, we may be able to help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error *usually*, but not always, happens because of an internal problem inside Google's processing itself. It usually indicates that they are still tuning the servers for performance and indicates one of their internal resources have been exhausted.

This is not too surprising while the service is still in beta.

The best thing to do when you get an error like this is to try again a few seconds or minutes later. If the problem persists, you can report it to Google using the reporting tool available from the three dots in the upper right hand corner.